# jQuery submit() only happens once, should happen more

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to add commenting functionality to my posts.
I can add the comment once and the partial is rendered without a reload, but when I add another comment it only renders the partial (nothing else)
Here is the create method I am calling:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @snippet = @comment.snippet
    @comment.save
    @comment = Comment.new
    render :partial => "snippets/comment"
  end
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    save_comment();
});
function save_comment() {
    $("#new_comment").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "/comments/create";
        var post_data = $('#new_comment').serialize();
        logger(post_data);
        post_data = add_auth_token(post_data); // add authenticity token to post for forgery protection (works fine)
        $.post(url,
            post_data,
            function(data) {
                $("#comments_container").html(data);
                $("#comment_value").val("");
            });
    });
}
```

And the form

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :value %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :snippet_id, :value => @snippet.id %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the html is being added after the event listener code is executed it is not able to attach an event handler for `submit` for elements added later in the DOM. You need to make use of the [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) api to bind the events and it will attach a delegated event handler that  can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

In your case you need to change your code to:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    save_comment();
});
function save_comment() {
    $(document).on("submit","#new_comment",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "/comments/create";
        var post_data = $('#new_comment').serialize();
        logger(post_data);
        post_data = add_auth_token(post_data); // add authenticity token to post for forgery protection (works fine)
        $.post(url,
            post_data,
            function(data) {
                $("#comments_container").html(data);
                $("#comment_value").val("");
            });
    });
}
```